# Checking for multiple values with CONTAINS

Tags: validation-rule, gdpr

I'm trying to condense this validation rule formula:

```
OR( CONTAINS( Email , "example@gmail.com"),CONTAINS( Email , "example2@gmail.com")
```

I want to use `||` logic but I'm receiving this error:

[image]

Do I solve this error by appending TEXT before email?

Comment: You cannot condense the formula in that way. "Contains" takes two parameters, one field and one value. The original way the formula was written is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

No. Simply put, that syntax isn't valid. The OR operator can't work that way, just as we can't write:

```
YEAR(CreatedDate) = 2009 || 2010
```

It simply does not work that. You could use || instead of OR, but that would only save a couple of characters.

Comment: So if I want to check 100 emails I'll have to use 100 "OR(CONTAINS( Email , "example@gmail.com", CONTAINS( Email , "example@gmail.com")...etc )?

Comment: @Nivi If you need "contains" functionality, then yes. If you're interested in *exact* values instead, you can use `CASE` or `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: these emails will be exact, so yes. I have a list of 180 emails that will go into the validation rule. Would that reach a limit of some kind?

Comment: @Nivi Take a look at the VLOOKUP formula. It's better suited to your purpose.

Comment: Just some clarification on my use case: I have a list of 185 email addresses. I want to throw a validation error when a user tries to create/update a contact with a matching email address from the 185 list. VLOOKUP is still a viable option here?

Comment: @Nivi Yes, that's the only valid use case for VLOOKUP, is during a validation rule, and it is designed to support your exact use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100546/discussion-between-nivi-and-sfdcfox).

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS function follows `CONTAINS(text, compare_text)` and you can use `:` between different values in the `text` argument to check `compare_text` against them.

So following your example, you can change:

> OR( CONTAINS( Email , "example@gmail.com"),CONTAINS( Email , "example2@gmail.com")

to

> CONTAINS("example@gmail.com:example2@gmail.com", Email)